# gcloud sdk in mac terminal - backspace does not work

Tags: gcloud, iterm2

Mac 10.14.6
iTerm2 Build 3.4.8
Google Cloud SDK 351.0.0
beta 2021.07.30
bq 2.0.70
core 2021.07.30
gsutil 4.66

Logging in to my virtual gcloud server without errors with:
`gcloud compute ssh myserver`

However, the backspace key in the terminal registers as a space key.

Tried exactly the same with the stock Mac terminal, the same behaviour.

What gives?

Comment: What is the value you have set for $TERM, and is it defined in /usr/share/terminfo? For example, when I SSH from my Linux machine:  

    $ echo $TERM  
    screen-256color  
    $ find /lib/terminfo -name $TERM  
    /lib/terminfo/s/screen-256color

(Sorry... struggling with the Markdown formatting.)

Comment: On my mac, $TERM is xterm-24bit

Comment: @Gerb thank you. The `find' command on the host does not list 'xterm-24bit', while the client passes it for the ssh session to the host, which it naturally, can't find. There are two options from here on: set some other $TERM on the host (with e.g. 'set term xterm') or add 'xterm-24bit' to the host's terminfo. You can make your comment the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backspace key will often seem to register as a space key if the environment variable `TERM` is not set to a value that is defined in your `terminfo` configuration.

You can check the value of `TERM` by running:

```
echo $TERM
```

`terminfo` can be configured in several places, but on Google Compute Engine it is likely using the values from `/lib/terminfo`. (Other possibilities include `$HOME/.terminfo` and `/usr/share/terminfo`.) You can check if your current setting for `TERM` corresponds to a file in this directory by running:

```
find /lib/terminfo -name $TERM
```

If the value is present, you will see something like `/lib/terminfo/s/screen-256color`. If it is not present, you will not see any output.

You can fix the problem by ensuring that your `TERM` environment variable is set to one of the files defined in `terminfo`.